# The console doesnt accept the command from shell script, works fine when the commands are written in (putty)console

Tags: shell, putty

I want to know the problem with my shell script.
When I write the following command directly in the putty it works fine

```
module remove gcc/4.4.5
```

However, if I pack this command in a shell then the error message comes:

```
module: command not found
```

I can't figure it out why it does'mt work in a shell and works fine when copy and pasted :(

Any suggestions to use it in shell?

regards

Comment: What is the output of `type module`?

Comment: module is a function 
module ()
{
    eval `/sysdata/shared/sfw/Modules/$MODULE_VERSION/bin/modulecmd bash $*`
}

Comment: hmm... thought so. This goes in line with my answer... editing the answer...

Answer (score 0):

Possibly, module is an alias or a function.

Try:

```
bash < myScript.sh
```

Replace bash with shell you want to use :-)

---

Probably it's because .bashrc is not sourced when running the script.

Try putting `. ~/.bashrc` or `source ~/.bashrc` at the beginning of your script - myScript.sh, just after the `#!/bin/bash` line

---

Or worst case, try this. ;-) (not a recommended option.)

```
user@localhost $ `cat ./myScript.sh`
```

instead of

```
user@localhost $ bash ./myScript.sh
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but the result is same.     what do you mean by bash which I use?

Comment: I am using linux.  and the extension of shells also .sh  , so what next to do?

Comment: At a shell prompt, type `shopt -s extdebug; typeset -F module`. That should tell you the name of the file that `module` is defined in, so you can make sure that file gets sourced from your script.

Comment: module 10 /sysdata/shared/sfw/Modules/default/init/bash                   that is the result of your suggestion.. but how to get in running?  your point in unclear to me.